# How to repeat `f <char>` in opposite direction when using `,` as the map leader?

Tags: search, normal-mode

I have `set mapleader=","` in my `~/.vimrc`.

How can I continue to repeat `f <char>` in the opposite direction, when using `,` as the map leader?

Is it possible to remap `,` in the context of `f <char>` or enter `,` without it being interpreted by Vim as the map leader?

Comment: If you notice that your mapleader overwrites an internal used key by vim, then change your mapleader. Or alternatively whenever you need the original key by Vim, temporarily change your mapleader

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt - can you recommend a good candidate for a map leader? I was under the impression that `,` was somewhat a standard amongst Vim users.

Comment: I don't use mappings a lot, but I use the default `\\` which IIRC is the default by the documentation.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt is right. Another good candidate is space.

Comment: Since "find in the oposite direction" is less used than `<leader>`, I would suggest `noremap ,, ,`

Comment: I've been really happy with `<space>`. Super accessible (I use mappings _a lot_) and rarely in conflict with other things.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt That surprises me. Would you say you're a "purist" (i.e. minimal plugins, fairly sparse vimrc, etc.)?

Comment: @BLayer I wouldn't call myself a "purist", I do have installed some plugins. I just don't have the need for some of the more popular ones, perhaps I am just too used to the old Vim way of doing. Independent of that, I tend to not use mappings a lot, because I usually forget what I have defined, unless I use it everyday. Therefore I prefer to be explicit and use custom commands a lot more. Just my personal preference.

Comment: @perelo - why is `noremap ,, ,` not being interpreted as `<leader>`, when `<leader>` is set to `,`? Does a key-binding circumvent the `<leader>`? I know of non-recursive mappings, but thought they only applied to other `*map` commands?

Comment: I solved the problem. I can just press `,` and wait for the `<leader>` to timeout, and then it's interpreted as `,`. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Right on. Thanks for sharing. Personally, I was what I'd call a minimalist for years. Well, that's being generous...I was practically a novice. Then I found the time to really dive in and about a year later started contributing here. Been creating mucho custom mappings since. Kept my plugin count pretty low, though, until the last year or so...have 20-25 these days (including Unicode.vim, which is great. :)  Cheers.

Comment: There's some information about the timeout you're seeing in `:h 'timeout'` and `:h 'ttimeout'`.

Comment: [popsikey](https://github.com/benknoble/popsikey) was more or less invented because I prefer mappings (shorter to type) but I couldnt keep track of all of them—labelling them makes them command-like.

Comment: @Shuzheng yeah that’s normal; after the timeout, vim knows there’s nothing else to trigger a mapping. So it does the only thing it can do.